# StringFormat Axis Label

Tags: wpf, formatting, charts

Where would I put my StringFormat={}{0:C} to make the axis label have currency formatting?

```
<DVC:LinearAxis Orientation="X" Interval="500000" ShowGridLines="True" Minimum="0" >
                                    <DVC:LinearAxis.AxisLabelStyle>
                                        <Style TargetType="DVC:AxisLabel">
                                            <Setter Property="Template">
                                                <Setter.Value>
                                                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="DVC:AxisLabel">
                                                        <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding FormattedContent}">
                                                            <TextBlock.LayoutTransform>
                                                                <RotateTransform Angle="60"/>
                                                            </TextBlock.LayoutTransform>
                                                        </TextBlock>
                                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                                </Setter.Value>
                                            </Setter>
                                        </Style>
                                    </DVC:LinearAxis.AxisLabelStyle>
                                </DVC:LinearAxis>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could help you
http://wpf.codeplex.com/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=75399

HTH

Comment: This lead me to the answer...added <Setter Property="StringFormat" Value="{}{0:C}"/> directly after my <Style TargetType="DVC:AxisLabel"> line of XAML.  Thanks!

Comment: If that's the case, then you could probably also put it just in your first line like: `<DVC:LinearAxis StringFormat="{}{0:C}" ...`. I've not worked with that control, but it must have a directly accessible StringFormat property to use a setter like that. Don't forget to mark the answer as accepted if it solved your problem!

Answer (score 1):

Not tested, but I think this will do the trick:

```
<TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding FormattedContent, StringFormat={}{0:C}}">
```

(It's the 7th line of your posted code.)

Comment: Negative, tried that - "The property 'StringFormat' was not found in type 'TemplateBindingExtension'.

Answer (score 1):

ContentStringFormat dont work anymore on SL4, this way worked for me, suggested by [andulvar on sl forum](http://forums.silverlight.net/p/38430/255932.aspx):

if you need only a StringFormat:

```
<TextBox DataContext="{TemplateBinding Value}" 
 Text="{Binding StringFormat='\{0:MM/dd HH:mm\} '}"/>
```

or if you want to use a Converter:

```
<TextBox DataContext="{TemplateBinding Value}"
  Text="{Binding Converter={StaticResource Double2String}}"/>
```

I hope this way help someone, I spent a lot of time to find the right way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Even better, you can go ahead and put a customized text instead of just a number or a Date on a X, Y axis. All you need is a Converter in between to translate a value (Number, Date) to a mush more meaningful text.

```
<chartingToolkit:LinearAxis Orientation="X" ShowGridLines="True">
                <chartingToolkit:LinearAxis.AxisLabelStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="chartingToolkit:AxisLabel">
                        <Setter Property="Template">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ControlTemplate TargetType="chartingToolkit:AxisLabel">
                                    <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding FormattedContent, Converter={StaticResource MileTextConverter}}"></TextBlock>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Style>
                </chartingToolkit:LinearAxis.AxisLabelStyle>
            </chartingToolkit:LinearAxis>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<Label> 
   <Label.Content>
        <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding FormattedContent}" ContentStringFormat="{}{0:C}" />
    </Label.Content>
</Label>
```